# Another div positioning next to the main div

Tags: html, css

I have a main DIV which is center of the screen with margin:0 auto; now i need to add another div outside (right hand side) next to the main DIV.. and the postition should not move if i increase or reduce the screen size... Any help?

```
<div style="width:320px; height:500px; background-color:#C60; margin:0 auto;">Main Div</div> <div>Another DIV</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want both of the containers to be centered together, or the main one to be centered on its own like it is now and the other one to be off to the side of it?

Comment: Yes exactly like that, the main one should be centered and the other one should come next to the main div.

Answer (score 1):

add to the style:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Or

```
float:left;
```

If you prefer the last one then you probably like to add a empty div after both divs that clears up the spacing

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`float: left` will work properly ...

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="outer">
    Main Div
</div> 
<div class="inner">Another DIV</div>
```

CSS CODE :

```
.outer {
    width:220px; 
    height:100px; 
    background-color:#C60; 
    float: left;

}

.inner {
    width:120px; 
    height:100px; 
    background-color:red; 
    float: left;
}
```

This is jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hAWQ3/)

**UPDATE :**

jsfiddel [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hAWQ3/1/)

Comment: But the main  div should be in center of the page, and the other one next to it.. any possibility?

Comment: use `margin` or `position`

Comment: add a div of the same width to the left. i know but i don't see a more practical option. or put the div inside the main div and float him outside of the main div.